Getting rid of the light grid lines when exporting map as SVG/PDF in QGIS
I have already tried changing the layer grid options in the Layout Settings and enabling the "Disable tiled raster layer exports" Setting in the Export Menu.
In the screenshot, you can see how the brighter Zone of the map does not have these seams. The Heightmap in the Background is a merged product of NASA Satellite Tiles. Could this have something to do with that?
Just South of the Rectangle saying "Hessen" you can see the seams I am talking about.


Which GIS software are you using?

I am using QGIS Version 3.38.0

How is your greyed out area generated/what do the grey/bright parts differ from each other? Whatever is generating the artifact must be something specific in the greyed out part

that looks like an artefact of the tiles - see if you can find a base map that is not tiled

i have created that base map myself, sadly i can't find any other versions, that fit my criteria. Since it was merged from NASA satellite tiles, i suspect it coming from that. but it only shows in the layout export. any settings, that might prevent this?
